# Ionic - ionic serve failed on web browser?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have ionic app that worked fine, until yesterday, and now it showing following error on browser console when run through `ionic serve` command. I didn't do any changes to any modules but this happens,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at registerNgModuleType (core.js:34470)
    at core.js:34488
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at registerNgModuleType (core.js:34484)
    at new NgModuleFactory$1 (core.js:34651)
    at compileNgModuleFactory__POST_R3__ (core.js:40286)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:40609)
    at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:13)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Object.0 (main.ts:14)
```

but the command line which runs `ionic serve` command does not show any errors,
I tried `npm audit fix` and `npm install` and no luck. Any Help here ?

Comment: seems you have an object in your code, which is undefined and it is trying to read `id` of that object. So check where you are using `someObjectYouAreUsing.id` in your code...

Comment: @AJT82 actually i haven't done any code changes except 2 `console.log` this is something else which i can't figure out for whole day today ????,

Comment: Are you using `id` somewhere in your code? Did you check? This sounds completely like an issue related to that.

Comment: Im 100000% sure, as a solution what i did was, i took the `src` directory and created new ionic project and replced the `src` adn installed all the required npm libraries, now it works fine

Comment: OK, well that's weird. But gooood you sorted it out :)

Comment: @AJT82 yeah, it's suppper weird, because it worked last night and not today morning, :-)

Comment: Yeah, ionic apps are "fun" in that way, they can break over night. I kinda have a love-hate relationship with ionic :P

Comment: @AJT82 yeah me too, but at least for me ``IONIC > React Native``